# fprintf and printf output order differs between the console and a file

Tags: c

I have a difficulty when I build my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char *input[2];
    input[0]= "ls";
    input[1]= "pwd";
    FILE *result;
    char *output = "output.txt";
    FILE *fout = fopen(output, "w");

    if(!fout){
        fprintf(stderr, "Can not read %s file\n", output);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char command[256];
    pid_t pid = 1;
    int num = 0;
    while(num < 2)
    {
        pid = fork();
        if(pid == 0){
            result = popen(input[num], "r");
            char getline[256];
            while(fgets(getline, 256, result) != NULL){
                fprintf(fout, getline);
                printf("%s", getline);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        else if( pid > 0){
            fprintf(fout, "#command %d\n", num);
            printf("#command %d\n", num );
            wait(NULL);
        }
        else{
            printf(stderr, "something wrong in process!");
            break;
        }
        num++;
    }

    if(pid > 0){
        pclose(result);
        fclose(fout);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I put `fprintf()` adjacent to `printf()` but result is different.

I get the following on my console:

```
#command 0
Debug
main.c
output.txt

#command 1
#command 1
/home/lightning/workspace/prac

/home/lightning/workspace/prac
```

In `output.txt` file:

```
Debug
main.c
output.txt
#command 1
#command 0
/home/lightning/workspace/prac
Debug
main.c
output.txt
/home/lightning/workspace/prac
```

Can anyone explain to me?

I would like the following output:

```
#command 0
Debug
main.c
output.txt
#command 1
/home/lightning/workspace/prac
```

`#commnad NUM` is printed from the parent process and the result of `#command NUM` is printed from the child process.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

It's been a long time since I coded in C, but if I read this correctly, you're opening a single text file, forking off a child process (which will run in parallel, more or less), having both processes *independently and asynchronously* write to that file, then exit.

Most likely the two process are writing all over each other on a character-by-character basis.

You have a couple of choices:

1. re-think your logic and have each process write to its own file
2. use file locks; have each process open the file for exclusive write (not a good idea)
3. use locks within your code so the child process is forced to wait until the parent process finishes writing (again, not a good idea.)

Comment: yeah thanks! just add a function which open-write-close each time write to file, work fire!